# I am trying to create a new file and add contents to the new file based on input parameters send

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create powershell script which will create new files and add contens in it based on input parameter (counter, file-name).
For every header line which starts with Ab a new file will be created and the line will be added from input file.
Once the line is already written it wont be written again next time in new file .The end line starts with Br , however i am getting error when putting in debug

> [DBG]>>> Stopped at: $_.PSParentPath.Replace("Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::", "")

Code sample

```
$fileinput = Get-Content c:\abc.txt
$fileinput1 = Get-Content c:\abc1.txt

foreach($line in $fileinput)
 {
    $array = $line.split(',')
    test-param $array[0] $array[1]
}

function test-param {
param ([int]$input1, [String]$input2)
$chunk = 0
foreach($line in $fileinput1) {
    if ($line.substring(0,2) -eq 'Ab')
    {
        $chunk++;
        New-Item -Itemtype 'File' -Path "d:\$input2"   
    }
    if ($chunk -eq $input1 -And $line.substring(0,2) -eq 'Br')
    {
        Add-Content -Path "d:\$input2" -Value $line
        break
    }
    Add-Content -Path "c:\$input2" -Value $line
}
}
```

Comment: IIRC New-Item wants a `-Name` or `-Value` parameter

Comment: According to `help New-Item -Full`, `-Name` is a required parameter, but Example 3 and Example 4 do not use it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest forcing $input2 to type "string" - if its not a string it won't be able to use the variable to construct the path.

Really need to see some sample content of the two input files to be able to comment further.

Purely from an optimization point of view, I would load the contents of $fileinput1 into an array outside of the test-param function. Everytime you call test-param function, you are loading the whole file again, which is way slower and will increase your memory usage.